# Batch File: Explode User Entered String Into An Array

Tags: arrays, windows, string, batch-file, command-line

I am writing a simple batch file that copies a video from a web server using a user submitted url. I would like to extract parts of the user submitted string and set them as a variables. Below is my example code.

```
@echo OFF
SET outputdir= %~dp0output\
SET libav= %~dp0libav\win64\usr\bin
CD %libav%
SET /p code= "Paste the download code from your browser: "
```

The user will be inputting a string that is in this exact format for %code%:

```
avconv -i "http://example.com/i/index_0_av.m3u8" -codec copy -qscale 0 video_name.mp4
```

I want to use a space as the delimiter. I need to set the 3rd item as %url% and 8th item as %filename%. Basically I am trying to do what explode() does in PHP.

The goal is to run the following as the final line in the file.

```
call avconv -i "%url%" -codec copy -qscale 0 %outputdir%%filename%
```

Comment: Btw. Apple-HLS streams are transport streams `avconv -i "http://example.com/i/index_0_av.m3u8" -c copy -qscale 0 "video_name.ts"`

Comment: And in case of `-c copy` you do not need `-qscale`.

Answer (score 2):

Although there are several ways to do what you want in Batch, the version below do it emulating PHP's explode:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set code=avconv -i "http://example.com/i/index_0_av.m3u8" -codec copy -qscale 0 video_name.mp4

rem Explode "code" string into "item" array
set i=0
for %%a in (%code%) do (
   set /A i+=1
   set "item[!i!]=%%~a"
)

rem Set 3rd item as url and 8th item as filename
set url=%item[3]%
set filename=%item[8]%

echo call avconv -i "%url%" -codec copy -qscale 0 %outputdir%%filename%
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For /f "tokens=3" %A in ("%CODE%") Do Echo %A
```

Which is same as

```
For /f "tokens=3" %A in ("avconv -i http://example.com/i/index_0_av.m3u8 -codec copy -qscale 0 video_name.mp4") Do Echo %A
```

I removed your quotes. Quotes only needed with spaces. URLs can't have spaces.

In a batch file use `%%A` ratherthan `%A` at command prompt.

If you need quotes see UseBackQ option where single quotes enclose string.

Answer (score 0):

```
:loop
SET /p "code=Paste the download code from your browser: "
for /f "tokens=3,8,9 delims= " %%a in ("%code%") do (
  if "%%b"=="" echo too few parameters & goto :loop
  if not "%%c"=="" echo too much parameters & goto :loop
  set "url=%%~a"
  set "filename=%%b"
)
echo %url%, %filename%
```

Note: the tilde in `%%~a` removes the quotes. Leave out the tilde, if you want to keep the quotes.

**Edited** to implement a simple input check